# Auto Layout: empty UITextField is only wide enough for 1 character

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitextfield

I'm trying to set up a simple UITableViewCell in which there is a prompt on the left and then a text field right next to it that takes up the rest of the width of the cell; however, with the following constraints, no matter what I set the width of the UITextField to, the width of the field is only wide enough for 1 character. Note: the UITextField is appearing in the correct position (it's directly to the right of the prompt), it's just really small.

```
cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[prompt]-[uitextfield]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views))
cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[promt]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[uitextfield]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
```

One solution that has worked is to set the width of the uitextfield to a ridiculously high number:

```
cell.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[prompt]-[uitextfield(1000)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: views))
```

I can't use this solution however because sometimes the UITextField is a UISegmentedControl (or other control), and I don't want to stretch those controls out.

Why is the UITextField forcing its width to be really small even if I explicitly set frame.size.width to something large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UITextField`'s content hugging priority along the horizontal axis should be lower than your prompt element's content hugging priority.

You can check out the content hugging priority by doing `yourTextField.contentHuggingPriorityForAxis(.Horizontal)`. And set it using `yourTextField.setContentHuggingPriority(250, forAxis: .Horizontal)`. You may also do this in the interface builder (which I prefer).

Try setting the text field's content hugging priority to 250, and set prompt's to 251.

Comment: Based on your answer, I was able to figure out a solution:            1) I changed the hugging priority of the uitextfield to less than 250 (all content hugging priorities were 250: contentView, uitextfield & prompt)  2) After making this change, uitextfield was still only 1 character wide (note: I didn't mention this in my question, but the uitextfield is appearing in the correct spot right next to the prompt, it's just really small). What made the uitextfield expand was to pin it to the right side of it's superview: "H:|-[text]-[control]-|"

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got the answer yourself. :) Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
1) Pin the UITextField to the right edge of its superview
2) Change the hugging priority of the UITextField to less than 250

Can someone explain why this works? Why doesn't it work to just do step #1? Or, if you only do step #1, why don't prompt & uitextfield expand equally to fill up the extra width in the superview?